# Creating a LINQ query that will include all entries from the current week excluding today and yestreday

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on a LINQ query to retrieve all records from the current week, however, I need to exclude any records from today and yesterday.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DateTime startThisWeek = DateFunctions.GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now).AddDays(1);
DateTime endOfThisWeek = startThisWeek.AddDays(6);
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

var notificationList = 
    (from n in db.DashboardNotifications
                 .OrderByDescending(n => n.NotificationDateTime)
     where (n.NotificationDateTime >= startThisWeek && 
            n.NotificationDateTime <= endOfThisWeek) &&  
           (n.NotificationDateTime != today && 
            n.NotificationDateTime != yesterday)
     select n).ToList();
```

The problem with above query is that it is not returning proper records , it also showing todays records too.

Comment: Looks like you haven't tried anything yet..

Comment: What have you tried?
we should know more about the structure of the objects you want to query.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: i tried it, in my linq query i selected start date of week and end date of week and checked today and yesterday over there . but it is not working.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky : i added my code black in question.

Comment: @Priyanka I edited your question slightly, please let me know if I misinterpreted what you were trying to say.  However, your question is missing 1 important part... why is what you have tried not working for you?  Is it not returning the correct records?  If so, what is it missing?  Or are you getting an exception?  If so, what exception.

Comment: @Priyanka is it Linq to Objects, Linq to SQL, or Linq to Entities?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky : linq to sql.

Comment: You are only excluding records for today and yesterday if they have the same time as when you run the report.

Comment: @sgmoore I recommend you try to craft that into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your `DateFunctions.GetFirstDayOfWeek` works correctly

```
DateTime startThisWeek = DateFunctions.GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now);
DateTime yesterday  = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

var notificationList = 
   (from n in db.DashboardNotifications
    where n.NotificationDateTime.Date >= startThisWeek.Date && 
          n.NotificationDateTime.Date < yesterday)
    orderby n.NotificationDateTime descending
    select n).ToList();
```

**Comments**: If start of current week is not before yesterday, then you will simply get no records. Otherwise yesterday always will be before current week end.

How to get start of week correctly:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime date, 
        DayOfWeek startOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        DateTime result = date;

        while (result.DayOfWeek != startOfWeek)
            result = date.AddDays(-1);

        return result.Date;
    }
}
```

Comment: If start of week is equal to yesterday then it is showing some records from yesterday date too..And in this case the result should be 0 records. How to resolve this ?

Comment: @Priyanka if start of week is yesterday, then this condition *n.NotificationDateTime.Date < yesterday* should not met. As you can see I used less than operator, not less than or equal

Comment: sorry, there was silly mistake in my code block. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You are only excluding records for today and yesterday if they have the same time as when you run the report.

Try

```
DateTime startThisWeek = DateFunctions.GetFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now.Date).AddDays(1);
DateTime endOfThisWeek = startThisWeek.AddDays(6);
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);

var notificationList = 
(from n in db.DashboardNotifications
             .OrderByDescending(n => n.NotificationDateTime)
 where (n.NotificationDateTime >= startThisWeek && 
        n.NotificationDateTime.Date <= endOfThisWeek) &&  
       (n.NotificationDateTime.Date != today && 
        n.NotificationDateTime.Date != yesterday)
 select n).ToList();
```

This is assuming that it is possible to have future notifications.

Ps, I'm not sure what the DateFunctions.GetFirstDayOfWeek method does nor why you are adding 1 day to it.